# convert Sql Query to Eloquent using whereHas instead of join

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

i want to convert this code to Laravel Eloquent using whereHas instead of join

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM
  (
     SELECT SEC_USER.ID, count(REPORT_EVENTS.USER_ID) AS counter
     FROM SEC_USER
     JOIN REPORT_EVENTS ON SEC_USER.ID = REPORT_EVENTS.USER_ID
     WHERE "PASSWORD" != '##NO_PASS##'
       AND "SYSTEM_ID" = 'CUS'
       AND "EVENT_TYPE" IN ('BILL','CHARGE')
       AND "RESULT_CODE" = '0'
     GROUP BY SEC_USER.ID,REPORT_EVENTS.USER_ID
     HAVING count(REPORT_EVENTS.USER_ID) > 2
  )
```

What I've tried:

Scope

```
public function scopeWithAtLeastTwoTransaction(Builder $query): Builder
{
    return $query->has('reportEvents')
        ->whereHas('reportEvents', function ($q) {
            $q->whereIn('event_type', ['BILL', 'CHARGE'])
                ->where('result_code', '0');
        });
}
```

Use

```
$report['count_of_users_with_more_than_two_transactions'] = \App\User::registered()->withAtLeastTwoTransaction()->count(‌​);
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: i tried to have a scope :
public function scopeWithAtLeastTwoTransaction(Builder $query): Builder
    {
        return $query->has('reportEvents','>','2')->whereHas('reportEvents', function ($q){
            $q
                ->whereIn('event_type', ['BILL', 'CHARGE'])
                ->where('result_code', '0');
        });
    }

Comment: Edit question and put full code

Comment: public function scopeRegistered(Builder $query): Builder
    {
return $query->where('password', '!=', UserController::DUMMY_PASSWORD)->where('system_id', 'CUS');
    }
public function scopeWithAtLeastTwoTransaction(Builder $query): Builder
    {
        return $query->has('reportEvents')->whereHas('reportEvents', function ($q){
            $q->whereIn('event_type', ['BILL', 'CHARGE'])
                ->where('result_code', '0');
        });
    }
$report['count_of_users_with_more_than_two_transactions'] = \App\User::registered()->withAtLeastTwoTransaction()->count();

Comment: Please edit your questions directly rather than adding your code as a comment.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: the version is 5.4